# How to save and restore the whole website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am developing my own router API in JavaScript. It does routing based on `#FregmentIdentifiers` (`document.location.hash`).

The API is almost finished but I am still working on the `backbutton` event. Whenever the `backbutton` is pressed and the hash has changed, and was seen before, the old content will be restored.

**Do you know a way to do the saving and restoring of all content?**

My problem here is that if I save and restore `document.body.innerHTML` only the markup is restored but not the events, so e.g. Googlemaps stops working.
I was trying to clone `document.body` or `document.documentElement` but JavaScript either told me that the field does not have a setter or that my clone is not valid.

EDIT:

To make clear after all what I am working on, I decided to post my current code.
The question aims at the parts marked with a `//TODO` comment.

```
function Router(){
var that = this;
var router = this;
var executionObservers = [];
that.routes = [];
this.registerRoute = function(route){
    that.routes.push(route);
};
var history = null;
this.init = function(){
    var i;
    var identifier = document.location.hash;
    history = new History();
    history.start();
    if(identifier.length > 0){
        identifier = identifier.substring(1,identifier.length);
        for(i = 0; i< that.routes.length; i++){
            var route = that.routes[i];
            if(route.contains(identifier)){
                route.getAction(identifier)(route.getParams(identifier));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
this.executed = function (identifier){
    var i; 
    for(i=0; i<executionObservers.length; i++){
        executionObservers[i](identifier);
    }
    document.location.hash = identifier;
};

this.addExecutionObserver = function(observer){
    executionObservers.push(observer);
};

function History(){
    var history = [];
    var timeout = 200;
    var lastAddedHash = null;
    var loop = function(callback){
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        window.setTimeout(
            function(){
                if(window.location.hash!=hash){
                    hash = window.location.hash;
                    callback(hash);
                }
                loop(callback);
            },
            timeout
        );
    };
    this.add = function(hash){
        lastAddedHash  = hash;
        window.setTimeout(addCallback(hash), timeout);          
    };
    addCallback = function(hash){
        return function(){
            var i;
            var found = false;
            for(i =0; i< history.length&&!found; i++){
                if(history[i][1] == hash){
                    found = true;
                    //TODO create backup
                    //history[i][0] = 
                }
            }
            if(!found){history.push(new Array(document.documentElement.cloneNode(true),hash));}
        }
    }
    this.setTimeout = function(micoseconds){
        timeout = microseconds;
    };
    started = false;
    this.start = function(){
        if(!started){
            started = true;
            loop(function(hash){
                var i;
                if(lastAddedHash!=null&&hash!=lastAddedHash){
                    for(i =0; i<history.length; i++){
                        if(history[i][1] == hash){
                            //TODO restore from backup
                            document.location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    router.addExecutionObserver(this.add);
}
}

Router.instance = null;
Router.getInstance = function(){
    if(Router.instance === null ){
        Router.instance = new Router();
    }
    return Router.instance;
};

/**
 * @param getParams = function(identifier)
 * @param getIdentifier = function(params)
 * @param contains = function(identifier)
 */
function Route(action, getParams, getIdentifier, contains){
    var that = this;
    var router = Router.getInstance();
    this.contains = contains;
    this.getParams = getParams;
    this.getAction = function(){
        return action;
    }
    this.reExecute = function(identifier){
        action(getParams(identifier));
    };
    this.execute = function(params){
        action(params);
        this.executed(params);
    }
    this.executed = function(params){
        router.executed('#' + getIdentifier(params));
    };
    this.register = function(){
        router.registerRoute(this);
    };
}
function PrefixedRouterConfig(prefix,paramRegexes){
    this.contains = function(identifier){
        var regex = "^" + prefix;
        for(var i=0;i<paramRegexes.length;i++){
            regex+="_"+paramRegexes[i];
        }
        regex +="$";
        var match = identifier.match(regex);
        return match != null && (typeof match) == 'object' && (match[0] == identifier);
    };
    this.getIdentifier = function(params){
        ret = prefix;
        for(var i=0;i<params.length;i++){
            ret+="_"+params[i];
        }
        return ret;
    };
    this.getParams = function(identifier){
        var regex = "^" + prefix;
        for(var i=0;i<paramRegexes.length;i++){
            regex+="_("+paramRegexes[i]+")";
        }
        regex +="$";
        var matches = identifier.match(regex);
        var ret = [];
        for(var i=1;i<matches.length;i++){
            ret.push(matches[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    };
}
```

An example usage of my api can look like this:

```
config = new PrefixedRouterConfig('show_map',new Array("\\d+", "-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", "-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
var ROUTE_SHOW_MAP = new Route(
    function(params){
        var zoom = params[0];
        var lat = params[1];
        var lng = params[2];
        MyGmapInterface.preparePage(-1);
        addTabSelectedCallback(MyGmapInterface.tabLoaded);
        addTabClosedCallback(MyGmapInterface.tabClosed);
        MyGmapInterface.tabsLoaded = true;
        MyGmapInterface.myMap = new MyMap(lat,lng,zoom,MyGmapInterface.getMapContainer(),MyGmapInterface.notCompatible);
        MyGmapInterface.addNewCamMarkers(MyGmapInterface.loadCams());
        MyGmapInterface.initListeners();
        tabSelected(TAB_LEFT);
    },
    config.getParams,
    config.getIdentifier,
    config.contains
);
ROUTE_SHOW_MAP.register();
```

After all JavaScript files are included (which may register routes) I call `Router.getInstance().init();`.

When I do somewhere an ajax request (by hand) for which a route exists, I call `ROUTE_NAME.executed()` to set the fragment identifier and to register it with the history.

Furthermore I have an observer which updates some links, which are used for direct translations, whenever a location hash is changed by `executed()`.

Comment: Ok I have started a bounty to this. 50+ for the one who gives me an answer to this question, showing working code. At the moment I am solving handling the back button event with a simple reload, but what I would like to prefer is, restoring from an history. this means, that as well markup and events can be stored, and restored. I just need the storing and restoring logic here. the event handling is done already. or would you say handling it with a reload is better?
Regards and thanks.

Comment: Your bounty is a waste of time, what your looking to do is both extremely difficult and extremely pointless. Browsers themselves handle cached historic pages, not the 'code' from the website. You could use PHP to restore a previous page, and pass in an object that contains on the historical parameters you wish to have set on that page. To be honest, a 'router api' built on fragment identifiers sounds horrific and prehistoric, you should re-invest sometime into learning modern web practice.

Comment: What I have a is javascript code, that set's a unique fregment identifier for each ajax request. By the fregment identifier the complete page is restoreable. But the back button at the moment does not work without a reload.

Comment: `document.body.cloneNode(true)` ? I must have missed something...

Comment: @tokam What _I'm_ saying is, this is wrong. I understand what your attempting to accomplish, I just don't understand why your needlessly trying to re-invent the wheel. What is the overall goal? What are you trying to implement? and why?

Comment: Would it be enough to listen to the hash change? There are JS solutions for that: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 8):

This is the same situation as a refresh so you should re-use that system.

Basicly your hash has to contain enough information to rebuild the whole page. Ofcourse, sometimes you need to save some user input to rebuild a page. That's where the localStorage is for (userData for IE)

Comment: I'd rather like to cache the page in the user's ram than reloading it from the server!

Comment: If your configuration is correct, the page request should give a 304 Not Modified response. So the browser reads the page from cache.

Comment: Ok good so far, but this means additional traffic for me. My thought was when developing a local cache, I can reduce server requests.

Comment: Build a system to cache the results of your repeating datarequests. So if the page requests the same object twice it doesn't send a second ajax request but returns the cached result. Ofcourse like any cache you have to remember to expire the results or you can get some strange bugs.

Comment: I already have, but if I do a reload it does. The answer here aims for doing a reload on back button pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've added your events through an API which tracks them (like jQuery does; see http://api.jquery.com/clone#true ), you won't be able to reflect on the events which have been added in order to get them serialized/preserved.

If you have made the unlikely choice of using DOM user data, you will also need [setUserData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.setUserData) to serialize any DOM user data (or again, a library like jQuery to track it for you).

Comment: I ask myself if it is allowed to copy the JQuery code without using JQuery, and where to find this code for clone()

Comment: I can not use jQuery in my project.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to know which part of jQuery handles cloning? What you can do is basically do something tracking the events `var Event={els: [], evs: [], cb: [], add:function (el, ev, cb) { el.addEventListener(ev, cb, false); this.els.push(el);this.evs.push(ev); this.cbs.push(cb); }};` Then you can introspect on `Event.evs`, etc. to find what has been added, and add it back when you do your cloning.

Answer (score 2):

What about having everything in an IFRAME and mirror all the URL fragment changes in the parent, then act on the iframe. Could be possible cross site scripting issue here though.

It's very difficult what your doing otherwise because **the browser caches** -- it decides whether to load from memory -- not you. So if the above isn't an option, the only way you'll create this is via a browser extention, which listens for the tab back button event and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#)?  I know in another post you mentioned jQuery was not an option, but you might mimic their approach.

I'm not an expert on the subject, but because of the different browser implementations, I believe *this is not trivial* to get working cross-browser.

Main site: http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/#

Demo page: http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/

Comment: I do not see where they do the saving and restoring, am I blind?
https://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/raw/master/jquery.history.js

Comment: This is leveraging *built-in* browser history implementations, rather than the more brute-force approach of storing the page in JS memory somehow. Basically, you instruct the browser to store the dynamic URL's / page states it wouldn't normally consider worthy of storage.  When done correctly, the back button works without additional work.  (As you can see, you need to get creative to do this cross-browser, using iFrames in some cases.)  I *think* the code that's setting the new (dynamic) location into browser history is `implementations.*.load();`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is practically impossible, you could do it if you used a library like jquery to build the events of your page like brettz9 suggested, but in your case you are using google maps and other external libraries so it's not an option.
The way to go here is to know which page you are on, and execute the javascript that initializes that page as if it was the first time the page is loaded. For that you need to keep track not only the html of the page, but also the javascripts that get executed when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to deceive the browser into believing that each worthwhile event is a new page. You could do that by loading a new page using window.location, or submit a form using get (=query string). The new location, or the form data, has to contain everything necessary for displaying the right information. This has its downsides - here's my view:

Good:

- back and forward buttons work
- views of your data can be bookmarked
- with careful use of query string data, it offers an API to your system

Bad:

- every worthwhile event has to go through a page upload
- can't take advantage of ajax
- you have to devise a way to encode every state of your system in query string form.